# R - "assign" function to calculate a sumif type of calculation

Tags: r, function, loops, sum

I've been using this code to run sums

First some dummy data-

```
Y <- c(356,392,127,127,437,392,392,450,155,181)
YearWeek <- c(201602,201602,201603,201603,201604,201604,201604,201605,201605,201605)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(YearWeek,Y))
weeks <- as.data.frame(unique(df$YearWeek))
```

Here is current code to calculate sums

```
Container_weeks <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(weeks)) {Container_weeks [i] <- sum(df$Y[df$YearWeek==weeks[i,]  ], na.rm = FALSE) }
```

results

```
Container_weeks
[1]  748  254 1221  786
```

I know this can be done in many ways but i need to specifically use the **assign** function instead of the above code. I tried this code below but it doesn't work.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(weeks)) {assign(Container_weeks[i], sum(df$Y[df$YearWeek==weeks[i,] ], na.rm = FALSE)) }
```

I get this error message

```
Error in assign(Container_weeks[i], sum(df$Y[df$YearWeek == weeks[i, ]],  : 
  invalid first argument
```

I've tried all manner of configurations within the assign function like "Container_weeks[i]", "Container_weeks"[i] etc. but nothing works. Can it even be done with assign? As mentioned, calculating sum can be done in many ways, but i need to use **assign** so i can adapt it to other parts of code and automation i'm using. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would strongly recommend putting things in `list`s rather than using `assign`... usually much easier to write and debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a group by `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(YearWeek) %>%
   summarise(Y = sum(Y))
```

---

Or with `aggregate`

```
aggregate(Y ~ YearWeek, df, sum)
```

---

In the OP's code, the 'Container_weeks' is numeric.  So, it should be converted to `character`

```
Container_weeks <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(weeks)) {Container_weeks [i] <- 
       sum(df$Y[df$YearWeek==weeks[i,]  ], na.rm = FALSE) }
for (i in 1:nrow(weeks)) {
    assign(as.character(Container_weeks[i]), 
           sum(df$Y[df$YearWeek==weeks[i,] ], na.rm = FALSE))
     }

`748`
#[1] 748
`254`
#[1] 254
```

NOTE: It is not recommended to have multiple objects in the global environment.  Also, assigning to an object with name starting with numeric would make it difficult to use because it needs backquotes

If the intention is to create object names with unique values of 'weeks', etc, use `paste`

```
for (i in 1:nrow(weeks)) {
    assign(as.character(unlist(weeks[i,])), 
           sum(df$Y[df$YearWeek==weeks[i,] ], na.rm = FALSE))
     }

`201602`
#[1] 748
`201603`
#[1] 254
```

NOTE: Here, we used the OP's example and was able to create the objects in the global env

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(YearWeek, Y)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210199/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-r-assign-function-to-calculate-a-sumif-type-of).

Answer (score 0):

I've been provided some changes to my answer. Have I followed instruction incorrectly?

```
Y <- c(356,392,127,127,437,392,392,450,155,181)
YearWeek <- c(201602,201602,201603,201603,201604,201604,201604,201605,201605,201605)
df <- data.frame(YearWeek, Y)
weeks <- as.data.frame(unique(df$YearWeek))


Container_weeks <- c()

for (i in 1:nrow(weeks)) {
  assign(as.character(Container_weeks[i]), 
         sum(df$Y[df$YearWeek==weeks[i,] ], na.rm = FALSE))
}
```

For me this doesn't run? is it just me?

Comment: thiss would be incorrect because you don't have any values in `Container_weeks` `Container_weeks <- c()` Actually, what are the object names you want to create.  Suppose you have `Container_weeks <- letters[seq_len(nrow(weeks))]`, then it would assign 'a', 'b', 'c',

Comment: `length(Container_weeks)#
[1] 0`

Comment: i'm assigning the sum Y for each unique value of YearWeek